# SQL Join repeatedly (M:N)

Tags: sql, join

How can I join one table with another table multiple times in SQL? Illustrative example:

Table "Couples":

```
+------+------+------+
|  ID  | ID_1 | ID_2 |
+------+------+------+
|   1  |  123 |  456 |
+------+------+------+
```

Table "Info":

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
| ID  | FirstName | LastName  | Gender | Season |
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
| 123 | Jon       | Snow      | Male   |      6 |
| 456 | Daenerys  | Targaryen | Female |      6 |
| 123 | Jon       | Targaryen | Male   |      7 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

And now I need a combined result, that needs to be "up to date" (***Info.Season* must be the highest possible**, but you cannot delete obsolete rows):

Desired result:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+
| FirstName_1 | LastName_1 | Gender_1 | FirstName_2 | LastName_2 | Gender_2 |
+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+
| Jon         | Targaryen  | Male     | Daenerys    | Targaryen  | Female   |
+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

I have no clue how to solve the problem, that IDs are not unique and I need to join the *Info* table "multiple times".

Comment: Step one: Join the table _once_ and make sure you alias it. Post your code for joining once

Comment: Welcom David! Please explain what is the logic behind to get your desired result

Comment: This is an illustrative example, but I need it for something more complex, where I need to join it 22 times. The logic is that I need a report for a soccer match, where are only Players' IDs and the date of the match. I have to replace the IDs with more information about each player, but that info must be relative to the match date.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the most current state of a player by using an SQL Window Function to order each player by `season`. Then you need to join the information table to the `couples` table for each person in the couple.

#### `actor_latest` CTE

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    GENDER  SEASON  LAST_CHANGE
123 Jon         Targaryen   Male    7       1
123 Jon         Snow        Male    6       2
456 Daenerys    Targaryen   Female  6       1
```

#### Resulting SQL

```
with actor_latest (id, firstname,lastname,gender,season, last_change) as (
    select
        id
      , firstname
      , lastname
      , gender
      , season
      , rank() over (partition by id order by season desc) as last_change
    from info
)
select
    left_partner.firstname as firstname_1
  , left_partner.lastname as lastname_1
  , left_partner.gender as gender_1
  , left_partner.season as season_1
  , right_partner.firstname as firstname_2
  , right_partner.lastname as lastname_2
  , right_partner.gender as gender_2
  , right_partner.season as season_2
from
    couples c
    join actor_latest left_partner on c.id_1 = left_partner.id and left_partner.last_change=1
    join actor_latest right_partner on c.id_2 = right_partner.id and left_partner.last_change=1
```

#### Results

```
FIRSTNAME_1 LASTNAME_1 GENDER_1 SEASON_1 FIRSTNAME_2    LASTNAME_2  GENDER_2 SEASON_2
Jon         Targaryen  Male     7        Daenerys       Targaryen   Female   6
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36d25b/10)

Comment: This answer is correct -- although it is possible that the OP is using an old version of MySQL that doesn't support window functions or CTEs.